# Arrays in Java Programming

Tags: java, arrays

So I need to make a program that will store user and computer input into arrays, but when I print the results it only shows the last values inputted. I can't get the array to store all the values inputted by the user and the computer.
here's part of the code:

```
do
{
  String[] user = new String[100];
  yourChoice = GetValidUserInput(promptString);
  for(int u = 0; u < user.length; u++)
  {
    user[u] = yourChoice;
  }

  randomNum = (int) (Math.random() * 3);

  String[] computer = new String[100];
  computerChoice = GenerateComputerChoice(randomNum);
  for(int c = 0; c < computer.length; c++)
  {
    computer[c] = computerChoice;
  }

  TheVictor(yourChoice, computerChoice);

  decide = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to play another game?");

  if(decide.equals("no"))
  {
    Results(user, computer);
  }

}while(!decide.equals("no") || decide.equals("yes"));
```

Comment: as a comment your while statement seems redundant.  You may want to just re-write it as while(decide.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List usersList = new ArrayList();
List compList = new ArrayList();

do
{
  yourChoice = GetValidUserInput(promptString);
  usersList.add(yourChoice);

  randomNum = (int) (Math.random() * 3);
  computerChoice = GenerateComputerChoice(randomNum);
  compList.add(computerChoice);

  TheVictor(yourChoice, computerChoice);
  decide = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to play another game?");
}while(!decide.equals("no") || decide.equals("yes"));

String[] user = (String[])usersList.toArray(new String[usersList.size()]);
String[] computer = (String[])compList.toArray(new String[compList.size()]);
if(decide.equals("no"))
{
   Results(user, computer);
}
```

Try the above code.. It will work. I hope you will understand the change If you have any doubt please ask in comment.

Comment: thanks this did work, i was wondering is there a way to make the two single dimensional arrays into one two dimensional array?

Comment: In this code their were lot of change in comparison with your code. I understood your game and then written the code. Please dont forget to mark this as accepted answer for the help of future visitors. Answering your question Yeah you can the make the two single dimensional arrays into one two dimensional array. just create a String[n][2] and loop through it, String[i][0] = user[i] and String[i][1] = computer[i]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to move the lines which acquire input within your loops.

```
  for(int u = 0; u < user.length; u++)
  {
    yourChoice = GetValidUserInput(promptString);
    user[u] = yourChoice;
  }


  for(int c = 0; c < computer.length; c++)
  {
    computerChoice = GenerateComputerChoice(randomNum);
    computer[c] = computerChoice;
  }
```